# Virtual Column creation in Snowflake SQL

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone know what expressions can be used inside a virtual column definition in Snowflake SQL? I am currently trying to use the LEN function within a CASE statement for a virtual column during a table DDL query but it is giving me an error saying that it is not a valid virtual column expression. I can't find any documentation on the topic so I was wondering if anyone here knew the answer.
Also, if it is the case that LEN is not allowed in a virtual column expression, would anyone have an idea for a workaround to this problem? Thanks!

Here is the example code that I've been trying to run within the virtual column definition:
`CASE WHEN -- WARNING: line 0, character 0: Syntax difference: [] or [^] wildcard characters for the LIKE clause. "OtherColumn" LIKE 'T%' AND LEN("OtherColumn") = (2) THEN REPLACE("OtherColumn", 'T', 'Test 0') WHEN "OtherColumn" LIKE 'T%' THEN REPLACE("OtherColumn", 'T', 'Test') ELSE "OtherColumn" END`

Comment: Can you provide the actual table DDL?

Answer (score 0):

There's no limitation on using `len()` or `like` or `case` within a virtual column in Snowflake.

Tested:

```sql
create or replace temp table tmp_test(
  x string
  , x2 int as (len (x))
);

insert into tmp_test
values('amigo');

select * 
from tmp_test;
-- X    X2
-- amigo    5

create or replace temp table tmp_test(
  x string
  , x2 int as (case when len(x) > 3 then 100 else 4 end)
);

insert into tmp_test
values('amigo');

select *
from tmp_test;
-- X    X2
-- amigo    100

create or replace temp table tmp_test(
  x string
  , x2 string as (case when x like 'a%' then 'Friend' else 'Acquaintance' end)
);

insert into tmp_test
values('amigo');

select *
from tmp_test;
-- X    X2
-- amigo    Friend
```